# In DB2, i need to select rows from a single column based on the value of a host variable

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpgle

> In DB2, i need to select rows from a single column based on the value of a host variable.

The db column can contain a 'D' or 'P' only.

The host variable can contain the value 'D' or 'P' or 'B' (all rows).

When the host variable is a 'D', I want to select only rows with a 'D'.
When the host variable is a 'P', I want to select only rows with a 'P'.
When the host variable is a 'B', I want to select ALL rows.

I am doing this in RPG using embedded SQL.

Thanks in advance

Comment: select * from table where dbColumn = :hostvar.  Works for 'D' and 'P', but stuck on how to code if hostvar = 'B'.  I prefer not to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Going to try...  select * from table where (dbColumn = :hostvar or dbColumn in ('D', 'P')).

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
select * from table                 
where dbColumn in (                           
case when :hostvar  ='B' then  'D'                           
     when :hostvar  ='D' then  'D'   
    when :hostvar  ='P' then  'P'                                    
end ,                                              
case when :hostvar  ='B' then  'P'                           
end
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> this will work... thanks all

Going to try... select * from table where (dbColumn = :hostvar or dbColumn in ('D', 'P'))

Comment: Shouldn't work because `or dbColumn in ('D', 'P')` should always select all rows. Try `or :hostvar = 'B'` instead.